# When did the "redo" keyboard shortcut change from Ctrl + Y to Ctrl + Shift + Z?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, undo

For the longest time in my childhood, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> was undo and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> was redo.  I remember at some point, some pieces of software started doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for redo, and I found it very jarring at the time.  I've gotten used to it now, but I still occasionally see software using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.  I believe I might have first seen it in Photoshop, but was wondering if others remembered this changing, and if so, had a sense of what influenced this.

Edit: I'm wondering if it's a PC vs Mac thing the more I think about it.

Comment: redo is still Ctrl+Y. Only a few programs changed to Ctrl+Shift+Z like Photoshop and Eclipse

Comment: I would simply say there are two standards.  And, no centralized authority to specify which one to use.  So, it's just up to each individual software developer.

Comment: Some of these programs may also allow you to rebind undo to Ctrl+Y. [Photoshop allows you to do so](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/customizing-keyboard-shortcuts.html) at least.

Comment: *redo. Argh I've lost my edit window.

Comment: As software engineer I use undo and rodo commands all the time. Using shift version is much more confortable as you do not have to change position of your hand over a keyboard. Also it is logical to assumed that shift key is reversing direction of an action as for ex. alt+tab vs alt+shift+tab etc. But for historical reasons apps probably should use both shortcuts for redo command.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+Y comfortably requires taking your right hand off your mouse and moving it to your keyboard. This is a massive efficiency hit when working quickly. I've always exclusively used Ctrl+Shift+Z for this reason and hate when software requires me to press Ctrl+Y without also binding Ctrl+Shift+Z. IMO, the best choice for developers is to just bind both key combinations to Redo.